# imap_body breaks

Tags: php, email, imap

I have a script that will transfer Mails from one source IMAP-Server to a target IMAP-Server.
I've written this script locally in my xampp with eclipse as IDE.
Local it works fine. But without INTERNALDATE. Because my XAMPP-PHP Version was to old.

So i moved the script to my server where **PHP 5.3.6-pl0-gentoo** is running.

**Step 1:**
In the beginning, the script will cache all mails of one Box to Files on the FileSystem (FileCache).

**Step 2:**
After the IMAP-Connection-Ressource is changed to target IMAP-Mailbox the script will do an "imap_append" on all cached mails to write this mails to the target IMAP-Mailbox.

I repeat, this script works fine on local machine (without INTERNALDATE)!
INTERNALDATE is only used on imap_append. So step one (caching) has nothing to do with INTERNALDATE!

**My Problem:**
On caching Mails it breaks after 4** mails. It is everytime the same mail where it breaks.
and it breaks everytime on "imap_body" this mail is nothing special: normal html with attachment (1x 32MB 7z-File)

On local machine this mail was transfered by this script.

**Some information about the execution:**

1. Execution Timeout of PHP is set to 3
   hours (script is running 3 minutes
   before it breaks).
2. Memory Limit of PHP is set to 1GB
   (machine has 2GB) script is using
   63MB before it breaks.
3. Socket Timeout of PHP is set to 3
   hours.
4. **To load the Header of this special
   mail works fine on both systems.
   Only to load the body will break.**
5. **In my analyse it breaks directly after "call_user_func_array" with
   "imap_body"**

**Here my Script:**

Getter of RawHeader of one Mail

```
/**
 * Getter of $_rawHeader
 * @access public
 * @return Content of $_rawHeader
 */
public function getRawHeader($update=false) {
        if(!$this->_rawHeader || $update) {
                $cachename = urlencode('imap_'.$this->getIMAP()->getInstanceName().$this->getIndex().'_rawheader');
                if(!($this->_rawHeader = $this->Cache()->get($cachename)) || $update) {
                        $this->_rawHeader = $this->getIMAP()->fetchheader($this->getIndex());
                        $this->Cache()->set($cachename, $this->_rawHeader, 2592000);
                        SYSLOG::debug($this->_rawHeader);
                }
        }
        return $this->_rawHeader;
}
```

Getter of RawBody of one Mail

```
/**
 * Getter of $_rawBody
 * @access public
 * @return Content of $_rawBody
 */
public function getRawBody($update=false) {
        if(!$this->_rawBody || $update) {
                $cachename = urlencode('imap_'.$this->getIMAP()->getInstanceName().$this->getIndex().'_rawbody');
                if(!($this->_rawBody = $this->Cache()->get($cachename)) || $update) {
                        SYSLOG::debug($this->getIMAP()->body($this->getIndex()));
                        $this->_rawBody = $this->getIMAP()->body($this->getIndex());
                        SYSLOG::debug($this->_rawBody);
                        $this->Cache()->set($cachename, $this->_rawBody, 2592000);
                }
        }
        return $this->_rawBody;
}
```

Call-Function on IMAP-Class:

```
/**
 * Catch not accessable Method-Calls
 *
 * @param String Methodname
 * @param String Arguments
 *
 * This Method is for calling IMAP-Functions without "imap_" präfix
 * Possilbe Methods are: Look at http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php
 *
 * @link http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php
 *
 * @return null || Function-Return
 */
public function __call($function, $arguments) {
        //SYSLOG::debug('Call Function "imap_'.$function.'" on IMAP-Connection: '.$this->getAddress().':'.$this->getUsername());
        if(function_exists('imap_'.$function)) {
                //Filtered Function that doesn't need Handle
                $filter = array(
                        '8bit',
                        'alerts',
                        'base64',
                        'binary',
                        'errors',
                        'last_error',
                        'mail_compose',
                        'mime_header_decode',
                        'qprint',
                        'rfc822_parse_adrlist',
                        'rfc822_parse_headers',
                        'rfc822_write_address',
                        'timeout',
                        'utf7_decode',
                        'utf7_encode',
                        'utf8'
                );
                //SYSLOG::info($this->_handle);
                if($function == 'reopen' && !$this->_handle) {
                        if(!$this->open()) {
                                return false;
                        }
                }

                //Make sure that the Connection is open if its needed
                if(in_array($function, $filter) || $function == 'reopen' || $this->open()) {
                        if(!in_array($function, $filter)) {
                                // Prepend the imap resource to the arguments array
                                array_unshift($arguments, $this->_handle);
                        }
                        // Call the PHP function
                        $func = 'imap_'.$function;
                        //SYSLOG::debug($arguments);
                        SYSLOG::debug('Call Function "'.$func.'" on IMAP-Connection: '.$this->getAddress().':'.$this->getUsername());
                        $result = call_user_func_array($func, $arguments);
                        //SYSLOG::debug($result);
                        return $result;
                } else {
                        SYSLOG::warning('IMAP-Connection not available! Call-Function: "imap_'.$function.'" aborted!');
                }
        } else {
                SYSLOG::error('Call-Function: "imap_'.$function.'" does not exist!');
        }
        return null;
}
```

Any ideas why it breaks?

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for my problem.
So i have found out that the attachment of the mail is to big. I don't know how it works local on my xampp but it is definitly to big for my productive system.

It's a workaround. Maybe not the right solution. I don't know. But it works.

I have replace the:

```
$this->_rawBody = $this->getIMAP()->body($this->getIndex());
```

with this:

```
//Workaround for imap_body because Attachment is to big
$this->_rawBody = '';
$tmpFileName = 'data_'.$cachename.'.tmp';
$this->getIMAP()->savebody($tmpFileName, $this->getIndex());
$tmpFile = fopen($tmpFileName, 'r');
while(!feof($tmpFile)) {
     $this->_rawBody .= fgets($tmpFile, 4096);
}
fclose($tmpFile);
unlink($tmpFileName);
```

Thanks everyone for thinking about my problem.